# first time using phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am getting nowhere setting up my first mysql database.  Is there a good tutorial out there I can use?

here is my code on a separate page.php

```
<?php
$db_hostname='hosting website';
$db_database='xxxxxxxxx';
$db_username='a4999406';
$db_password='xxxxxx';
?>
```

here is the code on an html page i'm trying to use as a login page:

```
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqu_error())
?>
```

i'm getting the following error:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'a4999406'@'10.1.1.47' (using password: YES) in /home/a4999406/public_html/willingLog.html on line 36

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading over W3 school's [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) first. After that head over to php.net - the site will become your go to bible.

Comment: thanks very much.. I love that site and tried their code. same issue.

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has great tutorials. Check out:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Follow the tutorials in order from there and learn how to start building on your MySQL skills.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

// some code

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it figured out.  on phpmyadmin using www.OOOwebhost.com for the database username you need to use the "MYSQL user" as opposed to the "Username" for the account.  One is related to the other so it's very confusing; especially since the tutorial says to ask for a "username".

If this doesn't work, i'll come back and post.

Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Ah you have an actual error message! Who setup your mysql database - was it an option you selected from your web host or did you run apt-get install mysql? If it was the webhost then yes I'd guess it is on one of their webpages that list the default database name/user/password.